# Angular form validation min/max attributes

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I just noticed that since the introduction of angular min/max validators based on the presence of min and max attributes something for me unexpected is going on.

We use reactive forms and therefor our validation lives in the component. We often however do add min/max attributes to the input for improved UX. I noticed these attributes now also work as validators for reactive forms and that the attribute in the template has presedence over a validator in the component.

Doing some research brought me to these two issues

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/39063
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42267

from which I did notice that I can use [attr.max] to keep benefiting from the native UX benefits but not use it as a validator. I find this annoying however, do you feel this is a bug or intended/expected behaviour?

**code examples**

This will validate everything above 100 as invalid and will not allow you to use arrows to go above 100

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl(null, Validators.max(500))
  });
}

<input formControlName="amount" type="number" [max]="100"/>
```

This will validate everything below 500 as valid and will not allow you to use arrows to go above 100

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    amount: new FormControl(null, Validators.max(500))
  });
}

<input formControlName="amount" type="number" [attr.max]="100"/>
```

I would expect angular to give a higher priority to the validator in the component for reactive forms and validate example 1 the same way as example 2 but now, to be on the safe side, we always have to bind to [attr.max] when using reactive forms.

What's your opinion on this?